# ionic refresh page on translate language

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

HI I want to reload page when user changes a language

Here is my code

```
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  this.appPreferences.fetch('language').then((res) => { 
    console.log('selected language',res)
      if(res){
        translate.use(res);
          // reload page with different language
      }
   });

  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page? I believe it will change the language dynamically for the translated strings

Comment: I need to manually refresh the page to see the effect of language

Comment: You are using ngx-translate right? It can dynamically translate the page and take the effect at runtime without the need of any refresh. Just make sure that you configured it correctly